# Spring Boot with QueryDsl

Tags: java, spring-boot, querydsl

I'm create a project Restful using QueryDsl  and Pagination. This is snip my code :

Repository interface

```
@Repository
    public interface PrsMainRepo extends PagingAndSortingRepository<PrsMain, String>, QuerydslPredicateExecutor<PrsMain> {
    }
```

and

```
 builder = new PrsMainPredicateBuilder();
    for (SearchCriteria param : body) {
          builder.with(param.getKey(), param.getOperator(), param.getValue());
        }
  // builder.build()=> prs_main.prs_firstname = 'Sharon'
    Iterable<PrsMain> main = prsMainRepo.findAll(builder.build());
```

When i run my project and test with postman , i see message in eclipse and get an error :

> o.h.h.i.QueryTranslatorFactoryInitiator : HHH000397: Using
>   ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
>
> > java.lang.NullPointerException

How to resolve this ? We are can show query generated when QuerydslPredicateExecutor excute ?

Comment: Can you give your entire exception stack trace

Comment: Hi @Nishant this is snip my ex stack trace  : 
    java.lang.NullPointerException
 at java.lang.String$CaseInsensitiveComparator.compare(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.String$CaseInsensitiveComparator.compare(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.TreeMap.getEntryUsingComparator(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.TreeMap.getEntry(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.TreeMap.get(Unknown Source)
 at org.hibernate.dialect.function.SQLFunctionRegistry.findSQLFunction(SQLFunctionRegistry.java:45)
 at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.util.SessionFactoryHelper.findSQLFunction(SessionFactoryHelper.java:369)

Comment: Can you try converting `PagingAndSortingRepository` to `JpaRepository` and see if this works

Comment: Thanks for help me. I'm already resolved, i'm wrong at builder() class.

Answer (score 0):

> We are can show query generated when QuerydslPredicateExecutor excute ?
>   For this you have to change configuration in your application configuration file. 
>   There is datasource section in that configuration and you can specify inside show/hide the query.